# Space of logical volume doesn't match space of filesystem

Tags: linux, centos, disk-space-utilization, disk-volume

I have a server running CentOS 6.4.
After installation, I had two logical volumes, /dev/VolGroup/lv_home and /dev/VolGroup/lv_root. I then deleted the lv_home and added the free space to lv_root.

So now if I run lvdisplay I get:

```
 --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/VolGroup/lv_root
  LV Name                lv_root
  VG Name                VolGroup
  LV UUID                fAme1e-o5CI-y4kT-j6jr-m99X-lciI-bh28KI
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2013-07-31 17:07:44 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                464,76 GiB
  Current LE             118978
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
```

But the space is somehow not available. When I run df -h I get:

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       50G   47G   17M 100% /
tmpfs                 3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   64M  396M  14% /boot
```

What am I supposed to do to actually have the 460G space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expanded the logical volume, but the underlying file system still thinks it only has the old disk available.

The next (and the last) step is to resize the volume; for example with ext* filesystems you do `resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root`. That should do it, and nowadays online with the mounted filesystem, too. :)